# OpenCL - Pass image2d_t twice to get both read and write from kernel?

Tags: image, kernel, opencl

In my OpenCL kernel I would like to both read and write to an image2d_t object. According to OpenCL standard I can only specify either __read_only or __write_only. 
However, I figured if I send the same cl_mem as two separate kernel arguments (one with __read_only and one with __write_only) I can do both.

Probably when I do a write followed by a read, I might get the old value(?) but in my case I would like the old value first, update it and write it back to the image. A simple example would be "increment each pixel by 1". It looks like it works in 99.9% but gives me artifacts sometimes.

Does anybody know if this is possible at all or if I have to expect undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

According to OpenCL standard, one Image can be used either for reading, or for writing within one kernel. So, if you need to read-write into same memory object, you have to use 2 Images, or switch to regular Buffer. No guarantee can be made that your kernel will work fine.

Comment: Correct for OpenCL 1.x -- you can't read and write to the same image in a single kernel. In OpenCL 2.x it is possible (but might not be optimal).

Comment: While this violates the OpenCL 1.x standard, in practice it works without artifacts on every device that I tested on macOS except Iris and Iris Pro.
This of course may be changed with future driver updates (in both cases). In theory, you can check the device name and the driver version on configurations you tested and enable in-place writing only when it works.