# OpenCL 1.2 read/write image data

Tags: opencl

I'm creating an Image2d object on the host using the flag `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE`.  This image is the output of one kernel and I want it to be used as an input to a *different* kernel.  I'm also using `cl_image_format = {CL_INTENSITY, CL_FLOAT};`

Is this possible in OpenCL 1.2?  I've read nowhere that says you can't do this, yet when I try my second kernel returns all zeros, but no error.

I've also tried using `clEnqueueCopyImage` to copy the output of the first kernel to a different Image2d (also created using `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE`) and using that as input to the second kernel, but that also does not work.

I've verified the output of my first kernel is correct.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, the output image from one kernel can be used as input to a subsequent kernel.

As long as the image is `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE` it can either read `__read_only` *or* `__write_only` in a kernel in OpenCL 1.x.

OpenCL 2.0 further allows images to be `__read_write` but special rules must be followed (such as barriers) to get correct results.

For more information on read/write image, please see https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-opencl-20-read-write-images

Don't try to cheat ([OpenCL - Pass image2d_t twice to get both read and write from kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114580/opencl-pass-image2d-t-twice-to-get-both-read-and-write-from-kernel))

Comment: Cool, thanks for the confirmation and the links.  As it turns out, it wasn't working because each kernel (and image) was being created within two different contexts, and I had two queues in there as well.  I've cleaned up the code and it's working now :)